# top "Command Name" column

Tags: ubuntu, process, top

On Ubuntu 18.04, I have a C++ compiled program MyServer.  `top -c` shows the "command line" correctly as ./MyServer, but the "command name" with `top` is shown as "main".

I wanted to know how to get the command name to be MyServer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be getting the command name from the main thread's name set by `pthread_setname_np`.

Comment: The answer is using knowledge that is not present in the question. If you could reformulate the question in such a way that this answer would have been possible to give without psychic powers, then it would be ok.

Comment: @Kusalananda But I thought that being psychic was required in order to reach a certain rep on the site...